# Quitting physics master's degree for another physics MSc. degree due to family/financial-health reasons

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, physics, germany, quitting

I'm now enrolled in the first semester of my first year in Germany (ranked in the best 100 universities) and I haven't taken any exams yet, since there's still at least 2-3 weeks for it. I never had any problem with the assignments on the courses, on the contrary, I always get the highest marks.

I have a decent CV with teaching experiences, grants, internships and 2 years of research in my bachelor and bunch of other stuff too but now I have to choose another master's degree program because my mother recently got diagnosed with last stage cancer and I can not finance my education considering the living expenses in Germany and relatively low (but high) tuition fees of the university.

I've already applied for the universities (for physics msc) that offers full scholarships (no tuition fees+scholarship). I was just wondering how bad it would look to quit one msc program for another program in the same field? (taking into consideration that I have a very solid reason)

Comment: Can you ask the university for some sort of emergency funding so that you can continue?

Comment: @Buffy Unlikely, there's no funding for master students in Germany, with few exceptions (then not through university).

Comment: You should be able to pause your study due to health reasons as well as family reasons. Talk to the Studienberater, or whoever is in charge, and possibly there is some councelling service for students. They could be able to tell you about options.  (P.S.: What do you mean by "relatively low (but high) tuition fees"? I don't recall there are places asking for tuition fees for your first master study currently.)

Answer (score 1):

Moving between different BSc/MSc programs, at least within Europe, shouldn't be seen as a problem: After all, one key point of the whole Bologna process (ECTS points etc.) was to make it easier to switch between different places in the course of your studies.  (Whether this worked is a different question, but at least, that's the philosophy behind.) So in fact, when you change programs you should not have to start all over again, but be able to (at least partly) use the credits you earned.  (This might speak in favor of trying to take the exams in the next weeks, or possibly postpone them due to the arguments given, rather than just dropping the courses altogether - given that many exams are online these days, this might be feasible.)